# Why does a large matrix pass through several subroutine tasks as fast as a smaller matrix

Tags: matrix, time, fortran, derived-types

### What Exactly is happening to my matrix? how is Fortran handling it?

What's attached is a snippet of code inspired from a larger
project that simulates light transport in eye tissue.  It
passes some large matrices through subroutines and then
randomly puts values in them.

My Goal: To see how passing such a large matrix through
several subroutines would have an impact on
performance.

My Reference: is the exact same code except the dimension of the matrix of interest is now [5,5] ( it was previously [250,200] )

My Question: Why is there no significant difference in results?

### MY RESULTS

---

- MATRIX A_rz dimension [250,200]

  real 0m6.661s

  user 0m6.638s

  sys  0m0.012s
- MATRIX A_rz dimension [5,5]

  real 0m6.508s

  user 0m6.489s

  sys  0m0.011s

---

### **bMatMOD.f90

```
module bMatMOD
  implicit none

  type :: INPUT
     integer :: nLayers = 1
     integer :: nPhotons = 50000000
     real, dimension (2) :: dZR = (/0.0004, 0.001/)
     integer, dimension(3) :: nZRA = (/250,200,30/)
     real, dimension (1) :: d = (/0.03/)
  end type INPUT

  type :: OUTPUT
     real, allocatable :: Rd_ra(:,:)
     real, allocatable :: A_rz(:,:)
     real, allocatable :: Tt_ra(:,:)
  end type OUTPUT

contains

  subroutine initOUTPUTS (in_INPUT,out_OUTPUT)
    type (INPUT), intent (in) :: in_INPUT
    type (OUTPUT),intent (out) :: out_OUTPUT

    allocate (out_OUTPUT%A_rz(in_INPUT%nZRA(2),in_INPUT%nZRA(1)))
    allocate (out_OUTPUT%Rd_ra(in_INPUT%nZRA(2),in_INPUT%nZRA(3)))
    allocate (out_OUTPUT%Tt_ra(in_INPUT%nZRA(2),in_INPUT%nZRA(3)))

    out_OUTPUT%A_rz = 0.0
    out_OUTPUT%Rd_ra = 0.0
    out_OUTPUT%Tt_ra = 0.0

    return
  end subroutine initOUTPUTS

end module bMatMOD
```

### **bMatRoutines.f90

```
subroutine A (o)
  use bMatMOD
  type (OUTPUT) :: o
  real :: rnd1, rnd2

  rnd1 = rand()
  rnd2 = rand()

  call B(o,rnd1,rnd2)

  return
end subroutine A

subroutine B (o,x,y)
  use bMatMOD
  type (OUTPUT) :: o
  real, intent (in) :: x
  real, intent (in) :: y
  integer, dimension(2) :: temp
  integer :: i, j

  temp = SHAPE(o%A_rz)
  i = INT(temp(1)*y)
  j = INT(temp(2)*x)

  if ( i .eq. 0) then
     i = 1
  endif  
  if (i .eq. temp(1)) then
     i = i - 1
  endif  
  if (j .eq. 0) then
     j = 1
  endif  
  if (j .eq. temp(2)) then
     j = j - 1
  endif

  o%A_rz(i,j) = o%A_rz(i,j) + x + y

  return
end subroutine B
```

### **bMatmcml.f90

```
program bMatmcml
  use bMatMOD

  implicit none
  type (INPUT) :: u
  type (OUTPUT) :: o
  integer :: i

  call initOUTPUTS(u,o)

  call srand(0)

  do i = 1,u%nPhotons,1
     call A(o)
  enddo  

end program bMatmcml
```

### **bMat.sh

```
rm -f *.o *~ *.exe
echo "MATRIX A_rz dimension [250,200]"
gfortran bMatMOD.f90 bMatRoutines.f90 bMatmcml.f90 -g -Wall -Werror -O3 -ffast-math  -o bMat.exe
time ./bMat.exe

echo "MATRIX A_rz dimension [5,5]"
gfortran bMatMOD-v1.f90 bMatRoutines.f90 bMatmcml.f90 -g -Wall -Werror -O3 -ffast-math -o bMat-v1.exe
time ./bMat.exe
```

Comment: One obvious explanation is that it takes effectively no time to process even the larger matrix (which isn't terribly large in the days of 16GB RAM laptops) and that you're measuring the fixed overhead of the rest of the code.  Don't discount this ludicrous idea until you have made measurements of much larger matrix sizes.

Comment: I agree. I would suggest to do that operation many times and (that is important!) don't use `./time`, but measure only the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Because you claimed you are a newbie, a few of suggestions: It is Fortran, not FORTRAN; you don't need your `return`s; `srand()` and `rand()` can't be recommended, use `random_number()`; instead of `.eq.` use `==`.

Comment: Much appreciated guys.  I will incorporate your ideas and follow up later! thanks

Comment: I wish one could upvote @Vladimir F's comments uncountably many times. May I also add that you write `dZR = [0.0004, 0.001]` instead of the ugly `dZR = (/0.0004, 0.001/)`; matching up parenthesis in large codes becomes increasingly difficult otherwise.

Comment: On style I like my INTENT to be (IN   ), (  OUT) or (INOUT), so that they are aligned vertically. I like a MODULE to either be implied as PUBLIC or PRIVATE, and when PRIVATE then declare as PUBLIC what you want exposed. For timing you may be best off to make a function, as you will find that you can use it in a lot of places. Having a separate StartTimer(TotTime, ET) and StopTimer(TotTime, ET) seems easily readable. If there are 5 or 6 different TotTimes, then they should sum to the total of the entire execution time.